# getting core dump in this simple threading program in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, segmentation-fault, stdthread

I'm new to concurrency in C++. I just tried creating new thread and tried running it.
But I'm getting memory fault(coredump) error.

Now able to find why it is causing memory fault. When I tried to debug using coredump created in gdb, I got this, but ont able to understand where the error is

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000603d20 in strcmp@@GLIBC_2.2.5 ()

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

void test(){
        std::cout<<"hi fro thread";
}

int main(){
        std::cout<<"hi fro main";
        std::thread myThread(test);
        myThread.join();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Crashing in `strcmp` seems surprising. None of this code requires that -- not even anything internal related to this code. What line (of your program) does _gdb_ show in the call stack? Perhaps you're linking at runtime to a different version of the standard library than your program was compiled against.